# h2o.ensemble, give the error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: h2o, ensemble-learning

I have a  problem. I want to make a ensemble model. The base models are gbm and neural network(nn). At the first time, I train these two base models and make ensemble model. And I save these two base models. The ensemble model can work. When I close the R Script and open a new file at the second day. First, I load these two base models. Howerver, I want two make ensemble model by using these two base models, which are saved in the first time. It will give the error: java.lang.NullPointerException. How can I solve this problem. Do I need to retrain these two base models before making ensemble model every time? This is so time-consuming.

Comment: Hi, I will need a lot more information & code to help you resolve this. Please post all the code you are using (ideally reproducible with a public dataset but at the very least I need to see code).  Also what version of H2O you are using?  Thanks.

Comment: More information about how to create a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example